# Geben for emacs on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: emacs, emacs23, geben

I've had geben running perfectly on previous versions of Ubuntu. After the upgrade, and installing the latest version of geben (0.26), it only half works. Specifically, when in context mode, local variables are always marked as undefined.

Has anybody successfully gotten geben up and running under Ubuntu 10.04, or is this a bug in geben (I've [reported it as one](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/issues/detail?id=4), but thought I'd check here just in case there is a workaround).

- geben 0.26
- xdebug 2.0.5
- emacs 23.1.1
- 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to xdebug 2.1.0 rc1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, looks like 2.1.0rc1 is indeed required.  I tried pecl's 2.0.5 (because apt-get install php5-xdebug gives you 2.0.4), but still no cigar.

For the whole shebang, checkout my [tutorial](http://ocdevel.com/node/497)